# How do I target a parent with only one child in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to change the background of a div that has only one child, for instance ?

Comment: There are no parent selectors in CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using this once support for [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) has been added.

`:has(.child:only-child)`